# How to display value of foreign key in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, gridview, foreign-keys

In a Web Forms ASP.NET application I have a stored procedure that joins two tables as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_DepartmentsServiceChannelsSelect
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT     d.ID, d.Description,  s.ServiceChannel
FROM         Departments d
INNER JOIN [ServiceChannels] s
ON s.ID = d.ServiceChannel

GO
```

So the Departments get selected with ID, Description and a ServiceChannel that is connected to a department gets returned as well.

This stored procedure I use in a Typed Dataset with a `TableAdapter` called `Department` that has the method `GetDepartmentsWithServiceChannels`:

```
static public DepartmentDataTable GetDepartmentsWithServiceChannels()
{
    using (DepartmentTableAdapter departmentTA = new DepartmentTableAdapter())
    {
        return departmentTA.GetDepartmentsWithServiceChannels();
    }
}
```

This method I use in a view to bind a `DepartmentCollection` in the code-behind as follows:

```
    private void BindDepartmentsAfterSorting(string sortexpression, SortDirection 
              sortDirection)
    {
        DepartmentCollection deptCollection = 
              ServiceInterfaceRegistry.DepartmentManager.GetDepartments(false);

        if (deptCollection != null)
        {
            Common.Comparer<Department> objcmp = new Common.Comparer<Department>();
            objcmp.SortClasses.Add(new SortClass(sortexpression, sortDirection));
            deptCollection.Sort(objcmp);
        }
        MyGridView.DataSource = deptCollection;
        MyGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Where `MyGridvIew` looks as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1000px"
            AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" EmptyDataText="Geen afdeling gevonden." OnRowDataBound="AfdelingGridView_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="AfdelingGridView_RowDeleting"  OnRowEditing="MyGridView_RowEditing" OnPageIndexChanging="AfdelingGridView_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="AfdelingGridView_Sorting">
            <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Delete/edit" CommandName="Edit">
                    <ItemStyle Width="20px" />
                </asp:ButtonField>
                <asp:TemplateField Visible ="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"  
           Text="Verwijderen" Font-Bold="false" />
                        </ItemTemplate> 
                        <ItemStyle Width="20px" />  
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceChannel" HeaderText="Service Channel" ReadOnly="True"  />

            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Unfortunately, the   `return departmentTA.GetDepartmentsWithServiceChannels()` part returns the following error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store 
>   in ServiceChannel Column. Expected type is Int32.

How can I make the `GridView` do display the string value of the foreign key?

Comment: read the value using reader through loop which you fetch for gridview by applying query, store that result in datatable and loop result into it and add datarow and store result in it one by one and then bind datatable with gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to make `ServiceChannel` object with ID property based on the datatable and match this object's ID in the `GetDepartments` method:

```
Department tmpDepartment = new Department(departmentRow);
            tmpDepartment.ServiceChannel = channels.Where(c => c.Id == 
                   departmentRow.ServiceChannelID).FirstOrDefault();
```

then this property can be accessed on the view via

```
e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Text = ((Department) 
                               e.Row.DataItem).ServiceChannel.Description;
```